# Two independent requests in one MySQL query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get a number of posts and a meta_value from a specific post by using the MySQL query from two different tables:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN post_type='updates' AND post_status='publish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS updates FROM wp_posts, 
LEFT JOIN meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key=content_version AND post_id=11242 AS version
```

Table wp_posts looks like:

```
|    ID   |    title   | post_type |  post_status  |
----------------------------------------------------
|    32   | Post Title |  updates  |    publish    |
```

And table wp_postmeta looks like:

```
| post_id |     meta_key    | meta_value |
-----------------------------------------
|  11242  | content_version |      1     |
```

Anyhow I cannot achieve results. Could you please help me?

Comment: Show your table structure please.

Comment: There is two different tables. Let me amend my question.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` should be after `FROM` and where is your `ON` clause to join?

Comment: Where is column post_status?

Comment: In wp_posts, just added to the structure

Comment: *I am trying to get a number of posts* no you don't. Since `wp_posts.id` is unique and you have `WHERE ... post_id=11242 ...` you always have **1**   or **0** `AS updates` you don't need any `SUM` there.

Comment: changing `id` in data sample to `32` change nothing in my comment `id` is still unique, and particular value of id is still in query `WHERE`. but now you just broke the relation between tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS updates, meta_value AS VERSION FROM wp_posts,wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='content_version' AND post_id=11242
```

Updated my Query

Comment: Hi @Lucky_Chingi thank you but it brings only number os updates posts and no results for meta_value from another table

Comment: is content_version a string ?

Comment: It is a number , can be 1 or 2

Comment: @qqruza check out my updated query and let me know if that helped

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f0fb/2)

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN aa.post_type = 'updates' AND aa.post_status = 'publish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS updates, bb.meta_value AS version
FROM wp_posts AS aa
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS bb
ON aa.ID = bb.post_id
WHERE bb.meta_key = '1' AND bb.post_id = 11242;
```

Result:

```
updates | version
2       | 1
```

Comment: I need to get the following view:
updates - 1 and version - 1

Comment: Change bb.meta_key = 'content_version' to be 1 or 2 according the values you have in that column.

Comment: How can I do it? Sorry for being so dumb

Comment: What values do you have in meta_key column of wp_postmeta table?

Comment: content_version - 1 and another row with _content_version - field_564251a1c3005

Comment: Also ID numbers of posts are different maybe it is makes it difficult to get results?

Comment: Check the SQL Fiddle in my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Kostas_Mitsarakis